# How can I convert a relative path to absolute path in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have a Dart code that need to take a path and work on it. For portability purposes I need the path to be relative and have Dart convert it to absolute path. How can I do this.
For example:

```
var samplePath = 'relative/path/file.txt';
// converted to 'C:/Users/XYZ/Desktop/relative/path/file.txt'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never programmed in Dart, but [in this part of the documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/absolute.html) there is a property of the class **File** which does what you want.

Moreover, if you have the root path of your relative path (maybe your current directory) you can join them using the [join function](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-path_path/join.html)

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 4):

Flutter 2.7

```dart
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;

var absPath = p.absolute('a/b', 'c');
// '...<current working dir>/a/b/c
```

[Documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/path/latest/path/absolute.html)